# Reemplazar cadena usando pattern para obtener thumbnail de youtube

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente string que procede del contenido de una pagina web:

```
String entrada = "<!-- verVideo('nClycKgfetU','65660'); -->";
```

Quiero transformar dicho string usando replaceAll (ya que puede haber varios) en:

```
String resultado = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/nClycKgfetU/0.jpg"
```

Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
x.replaceAll("<!-- verVideo\\('", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/").replaceAll(",'65660'); -->", "/0.jpg");
```

El primer replaceAll funciona bien, pero el segundo no funcionará **porque  el numero 65660 es variable y aleatorio**. Supongo que hay que reemplazarlo con algun pattern de java pero no logro averiguar cual es.

Comment: En la `URL` la parte de `http://img.youtube.com/vi/`  y `0.jpg` será fija ? , solo cambiará  el primera parámetro de la función `verVideo`?

Comment: Efectivamente, en la url "http://img.youtube.com/vi/nClycKgfetU/0.jpg" lo unico que variará es el ID "nClycKgfetU". El resto es siempre lo mismo para cualquier ID que se introduzca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, tras un rato haciendo pruebas, di con la respuesta:

```
entrada.replaceAll("<!-- verVideo\\('", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/").replaceAll("','\\d+'\\); -->", "/0.jpg");
```

La clave era añadir el `\\d+` para que coja cualquier numero entre las dos comillas